# Query String generated by $.param() include square brackets for array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like this:

```
var queryObject= {
      name: 'Shwetanka',
      subjects: ['Mathematics', 'Physics', 'Computers'],
      stream: 'science'
    };
```

When I create query string with this using `$.param(queryObject)` I get this as query string:

```
name=Shwetanka&subjects%5B%5D=Mathematics&subjects%5B%5D=Physics&subjects%5B%5D=Computers&stream=science
```

Expected: `name=Shwetanka&subjects=Mathematics&subjects=Physics&subjects=Computers&stream=science`

How do avoid `[]` added by the method in the query string for params with same name. In the backend I'm using [struts2](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/) to read params.

Comment: You wont be able to avoid the []'s, because subject is an array it has to use subjects[] to define each element. You could define it such as `subject1:'Maths',subject2:'physics'` etc.

Comment: Could you show us the expected query string?

Comment: I've edited the question with expected query string.

Comment: Show server side method, that read this request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution. I just have to pass 'traditional=true' in `$.param(queryObject, true)`. This generates the query string i want.

Answer (score 0):

When we have fields with same name in a form and it is submitted via `GET/POST`, it is bound to be send as an array of params with the same name. 
  And the server would be expecting the values as such. So, Even if you somehow remove that `[]`, it ceases to be an array, and the server will get only one value.
jQuery param method is designed, with the same thing in mind.
Check out examples in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/.